# How can I link a page with posts?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to create a virtual store and when I click on the store page I would like the product posts to appear. How can I link a page with product posts?

Can anybody help me?

Or would you have some examples of how I can do this?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily putting woocommerce shortcode like this, [featured_products per_page="12" columns="4"]

Best theme for virtual store [negard Theme](https://www.hedows.com/product/negard-responsive-multi-purpose-theme/). Buy this theme and get free developer for limited time

Answer (score 0):

You can call the Wp_Query with custom post type arguments and then you can link all the products to your specific page...